# Definition of rank

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher P146, the **rank** of a finitely generated abelian group is defined to be the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ summands when the group is expressed as a direct sum of cyclic groups.

$\mathbb{Q}$ $1$: What does "$\mathbb{Z}$ summands" really mean? For example, $H_2(K \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z \oplus Z_2}$. So the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ summands is 1? In other words, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ does not count?

$\mathbb{Q}$ $2$: Is the rank of $H_n$ equal to the number of $n$-cells? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question $1$, you are correct. The rank is $1$. For question $2$, you can say that the rank of $H_n$ is less than or equal to the number of $n$-cells. This is because in cellular homology, $H_n$ is a quotient of a subgroup of $C_n\cong \mathbb Z^{\text{number of $n$-cells}}$. Combine this with the observation that taking quotients and subgroups reduce rank.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Parsnip. I'll go back to read more about cellular homology.

Comment: @Jellyfish: That's a good name. I might stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is more about commutative algebra than algebraic topology : a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module (or $A$-module with $A$ a principal ideal domain for that matter) $M$ has the property that $M / M_{\mathrm{tors}}$ is a finitely generated free $\mathbb Z$-module, i.e.
$$M / M_{\mathrm{tors}} \simeq \mathbb Z^s \qquad \text{for some $s \in \mathbb N$.} $$
The rank of $M$ is defined as $s$.

Applying to your example, the torsion part of $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ is precisely $\mathbb Z_2$, which yields
$$ (\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2) / (\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2)_{\mathrm{tors}} \simeq \mathbb Z .$$